# If $p(x) = ax^3 + bx^2+cx+105$, $a+b+c=0$, $a,b,c \in \mathbb{Z}$ then $f(x)=0$ having no roots $\in \mathbb{Z}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials

> If $p(x) = ax^3 + bx^2+cx+105$,$a+b+c=0$, $a,b,c \in \mathbb{Z}$ then $f(x)=0$ having no roots $\in \mathbb{Z}$

I need some hint how to prove them?

Comment: It's not true in general.  Take $a,b=0, c=-1$ for example.

Comment: Many thanks, I added $a+b+c=0$

Comment: Hint:  let $p(x)=f(x)-105$.  Show that $p(x)$ factors completely over $\mathbb Z$ and write down the the factoring.

Comment: I don't see next step @lulu

Comment: Have you written out the factors of $p(x)$?  It's quite easy.  Do that first.  Should note:  the posted solutions look fine to me.  My method gets at the same contradiction, but they have a different way to get there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We note that $f(x) = 0$ can't have any even integer solutions, as otherwise $f(x)$ would be odd, while $0$ is even. Let $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ be odd, so $n \equiv 1 \pmod{2}$, which implies that $n^3 \equiv n^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{2}$. Then:

$$
f(n) \equiv an^3 + bn^2 + cn + 105 \equiv a+b+c + 105 \equiv  1 \pmod{2}
$$

Hence, $f(n)$ will never be even, so can't be $0$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** look at what happens modulo $2$. Show that $p(x)$ is nonzero modulo $2$ for any $x\in{\mathbb Z}$.

Comment: I am a bit confusing. Can you explain your idea more?

Answer (score 1):

Since $c=-a-b$ we have $$p(x) = x(x-1)(ax+a+b)+105$$

so if for some integer $x$ we have $p(x)=0$ then $$x(x-1)(ax+a+b) =-105$$

Since one of $x$ or $x-1$ is even, this can not be.